# App Keeps Crashing when I add a EmptyView or Footer to CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin

My app keeps crashing when I add an EmptyView for Footer to the collectionview the error log:

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid Query. Null supports only equality comparisons (via whereEqualTo()).'

however if I remove the emptyview and footer from the collectionview it works fine.

Xmal Code

```
<RefreshView Grid.Row="1" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding ReloadCloudDataCmd}">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PostCollection}" Margin="10,0" RemainingItemsThreshold="2" 
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding FetchMoreCloudDataCmd}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Post">
                    <Frame Padding="10" CornerRadius="10" OutlineColor="Transparent">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto, *, auto, auto">
                                <template:ImagesTemplate Grid.Row="0" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ffProfileImage}" SourceImage="{Binding ProfileImage}"
                                            xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference homepg}, Path=BindingContext.ViewUserProfileCmd}"
                                            xct:TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding UserName}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="{StaticResource Text_T2}"/>
                                            <Span Text="&#xa;"/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding PostedDate}" FontSize="{StaticResource Text_T5}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>

                                <template:IconTemplate Grid.Column="2" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource IconBtn}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding ShowBtns}" ClickedParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                IconGlyph="comments" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                ClickedCmd="{Binding Source={x:Reference homepg}, Path=BindingContext.OpenPostChatCmd}"/>

                                <template:IconTemplate Grid.Column="3" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource IconBtn}"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding ShowBtns}" IconGlyph="ellipsis-h" 
                                                ClickedParameter="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                ClickedCmd="{Binding Source={x:Reference homepg}, Path=BindingContext.ItemOptionsCmd}"/>

                            </Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource Label_L2B}"/>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="450" IsVisible="{Binding ShowImageView}">
                                <CarouselView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" IndicatorView="indicatorView" Loop="False">
                                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ImageLink">
                                            <template:ImagesTemplate ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ImagePostView}" IsLoadingImage="{Binding IsImageLoaded}"
                                                                 SourceImage="{Binding PostImages}" LoadingCmd="{Binding LoadingCmd}" SuccessCmd="{Binding SuccessCmd}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CarouselView>
                                <IndicatorView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="indicatorView" Style="{StaticResource Indicator}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Detail}" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                               IsVisible="{Binding CanShowDetails, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"
                               xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding ShowDetailsCmd}" Style="{StaticResource Label_L4}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Detail}" IsVisible="{Binding CanShowDetails}"
                               xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding ShowDetailsCmd}" Style="{StaticResource Label_L4}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <ContentView>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Nothng to show"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentView>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

Comment: I  test with your code everything works fine , would you mind sharing us a basic , reproducible project to test ? You can upload to github and attach the repo link here .

Comment: Thanks a lot for making time to test my code.. 
I found the issue it was with my **RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand** was trying to fetch more data that depends in the id of my initial fetched data since my initial data was empty it was trying to fetch with a null.
Solution was if my initial data count is equals 0 return.
That worked fine.
Thanks once again.